# C++ - Class definition with syntax using DLL

Tags: c++, dll

What does it mean exactly when I define a class this way in C++ project:

class THIS_DLL_NAME class_name{
...
}

thanks!

Comment: very probably, `THIS_DLL_NAME` is some macro. Check in header files what it is...

Comment: The only thing that really fits there is __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: Exporting classes is very fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Basile and Hans stated in the comments above, THIS_DLL_NAME will be a macro that conditionally expands depending on whether you are building the library itself, or code that just uses that library.

(BTW, I'm assuming you're on Windows here, due to the DLL terminology.)

`THIS_DLL_NAME` can expand to either `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)`. When the header file is included in the .cpp files that you're compiling into THIS_DLL.dll, the compiler needs to see `__declspec(dllexport)` in order to generate the proper entry points to export them from the DLL.

When your class header is included in code that is using THIS_DLL.dll, the compiler needs to see `__declspec(dllimport)` in order to generate the right code to import the symbol (and resolve it at runtime).

You can read up on more of the details straight from Microsoft in this article - [Importing and Exporting (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h658af8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).